# Use of NameTabels/Atomized Strings

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Use of a nametable:
I understood that its much faster to check for equality of two objects, instead of using the char by char string comparer.(If you get the object from the nametable, it will always return the same reference)
(An atomized string is just an string in a nametable)

Greetings

Comment: Any namespace prefix must be defined before it is used when parsing an xml file.  Sometimes the definition is in the webpage for a different xml.  The links you provided aren't for valid xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.nametable(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Implements a single-threaded XmlNameTable.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> Several classes, such as XmlDocument and XmlReader, use the NameTable
> class internally to store attribute and element names. When an element
> or attribute name occurs multiple times in an XML document, it is
> stored only once in the NameTable.
>
> The names are stored as common
> language runtime (CLR) object types. This enables you to do object
> comparisons on these strings rather than a more expensive string
> comparison. These string objects are referred to as atomized strings.

Comment: @user6216224:- Which point? Did you see these links? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879728/can-i-use-predefined-namespaces-when-loading-an-xdocument and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934486/how-do-i-get-a-nametable-from-an-xdocument

Comment: That is the point i don't understand: -If name occurs multiple times, that are stored in this object only once, and then evrytime the name occurs, its reffering to the same object? -What is the difference between normal and atomized strings (Probelms with the App ;) )