# Adding namespace to xml document programmatically

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use predefined namespaces when loading an XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879728/can-i-use-predefined-namespaces-when-loading-an-xdocument)

I have following xml nodes in a xml document:

```
<g:games>
</g:games>
```

But when this file comes to me it is missing namespace url. Is there a way to add the namespace url in .net 3.5? I am using Linq so using XDocument.Load command to load xml file.

In older version we can do this through xmlschema but its not working on XDocument?

Comment: @madd0 - Hi, I dont think it is a duplicate i simply need to add namespace but other document does lot of other stuff by creating seperate table and other things. I just need to add namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that what I suggested as an answer is unnecessarily complex. The code below should allow you to read your document:

```
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
mgr.AddNamespace("g", "http://tempuri.org");
var ctx = new XmlParserContext(null, mgr, null, XmlSpace.Default);

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"d:\dev\temp\sample.xml", null, ctx))
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

Granted, it seems like a lot of work for very little, but the only other alternative would be to edit the XML file before loading it with `XDocument`, but depending on where you are reading your file from (a network stream, for example), this could be an even more complicated option.

Comment: Sorry but this again seems complex. Isn't there a easy way just to add a namespace to xml file? Than load the file as XDocument.Load("filepath"); ??

Comment: Short of editing the original file, which I added as an edit to my original answer, using the `XmlNamespaceManager` is the only way to manage namespaces from "outside" the file (it's in the name...)