# How to change or inherit the default namespace when setting InnerXml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

When setting the `InnerXml` of an `XmlElement` having a default namespace, all tags without explicit namespaces *are parsed as if they have `xmlns=""`*, instead of inheriting that `XmlElement`'s default namespace (which is what happens when parsing a real XML document).

My question is: **how to parse a complex XML string as a document fragment and assign it to an `XmlElement`, and inheriting the target `XmlElement`'s namespace prefixes, default namespace, etc. when parsing that string?**

Disclaimer:

- I am totally aware of what XML namespaces are and what is the exact behavior of `XmlElement.InnerXml` regarding to XML namespaces. *I'm not asking why `XmlElement.InnerXml` is doing what it currently does, or whether such behavior is good or bad*. I'm asking if I can change this behavior or use some other techniques to achieve what I've described above.
- I'm implementing some kind of XML template system, which allows users to insert some rather complex XML strings as fragments into another XML document. It will be insane to require users to always use explicit namespaces (the overhead of writing redundant namespace declarations can easily defeat the benefit of templating). **I want a method to parse them and insert the resulting fragments into the main document as if they are literally copy-and-pasted into the target**.
- I'm aware that it is possible to preserve the default namespaces with pure DOM operations (like `XmlDocument.CreateElement`), but **I don't want to manually implement an XML parser and convert XML strings into DOM operations**.
- I also **don't want** to do "serialize the whole XML document, do **string manipulation**, and parse it back" kind of things.

Is it possible?

Comment: The use XML Linq instead of the legacy net library XmlElement.  With linqw you can find elements like this : doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName = My_Tag).ToList().  Using local name ignores the namespace.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlparsercontext?view=net-6.0#examples that shows how to set up an XmlParserContext with an XmlNamespaceManager to parse a string of XML with some namespace context. I would expect that to work also if the XmlNamespaceManager assigns a URL to the empty prefix "" but it seems that doesn't work as I expect, the elements without a prefix still end up being put in no namespace. So I guess you can create a dummy element container wrapper around your XML string that has the right namespace declaration(s), parse and then return its child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72740501/how-to-change-or-inherit-the-default-namespace-when-setting-innerxml#comment128486414_72740501) by [Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435262) by [Gideon Engelberth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174594/gideon-engelberth) to *[Can I use predefined namespaces when loading an XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/879728/3744182)*, you can use an [`XmlParserContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlparsercontext?view=net-6.0) to predefine a value for a namespace (including the default namespace) when parsing XML via `XmlReader`.  Using an `XmlReader` configured with an appropriate context, you can load your inner XML directly into your `XmlElement` and and inherit any required namespaces from its scope.

To inherit just the default namespace, create the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static void SetInnerXmlAndInheritDefaultNamespace(this XmlElement xmlElement, string innerXml)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StringReader(innerXml))
            xmlElement.SetInnerXmlAndInheritDefaultNamespace(textReader);
    }
    
    public static void SetInnerXmlAndInheritDefaultNamespace(this XmlElement xmlElement, TextReader innerTextReader)
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        mgr.AddNamespace("", xmlElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(""));
        XmlParserContext ctx = new XmlParserContext(null, mgr, null, XmlSpace.Default);
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(innerTextReader, new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment, CloseInput = false }, ctx))
        using (var writer = xmlElement.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
        }
    }
}
```

To inherit all namespaces (the requirements in your question aren't entirely clear), create the following:

```
public static partial class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static void SetInnerXmlAndInheritNamespaces(this XmlElement xmlElement, string innerXml)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StringReader(innerXml))
            xmlElement.SetInnerXmlAndInheritNamespaces(textReader);
    }
    
    public static void SetInnerXmlAndInheritNamespaces(this XmlElement xmlElement, TextReader innerTextReader)
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        var navigator = xmlElement.CreateNavigator();
        foreach (var pair in navigator.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.ExcludeXml))
            mgr.AddNamespace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        XmlParserContext ctx = new XmlParserContext(null, mgr, null, XmlSpace.Default);
        using (var writer = navigator.AppendChild())
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(innerTextReader, new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment, CloseInput = false }, ctx))
        {
            writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming `xmlElement` is the existing `XmlElement` to which you want to insert an `innerXml` string, you can do:

```
xmlElement.SetInnerXmlAndInheritDefaultNamespace(innerXml);
```

E.g. if your XML Document looks like:

```xml
<Root xmlns="defaultNameSpace" xmlns:d="dataNodeNamespace"><d:Data></d:Data></Root>
```

And you add the following XML to `<d:Data>`:

```xml
<ElementToAdd Id="10101"><InnerValue>my inner value</InnerValue></ElementToAdd><ElementToAdd Id="20202"><InnerValue>another inner value</InnerValue></ElementToAdd>
```

The result will be:

```xml
<Root xmlns="defaultNameSpace" xmlns:d="dataNodeNamespace">
  <d:Data>
    <ElementToAdd Id="10101">
      <InnerValue>my inner value</InnerValue>
    </ElementToAdd>
    <ElementToAdd Id="20202">
      <InnerValue>another inner value</InnerValue>
    </ElementToAdd>
  </d:Data>
</Root>
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lDjGIC) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kxtfXL).